# Time complexity (in big-O notation) of the following code?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

I was just wondering what is the time complexity of the following code.

The time complexity (Big O) of the code below in my opinion would be O(n^4)

What do you guys think?

```
int result = 0;
for(int i =1; i<n*n; i++){
  for (int j=i; j*j <n; j++){
    for(int k =j; k*k <n; k++){
      result++;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: What about an experiment. Run this code for n = 1 to 100, and print out "result" each time. That should make you think that O (n^4) is quite unlikely to be the right answer. On the other hand, the value of "result" doesn't really give you the time complexity reliably.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `n^(2.75)` to me:

```
- outer loop: n^2
- first inner loop is sqrt(n)
- second inner loop is sqrt(sqrt(n))
```

Total of:

```
n^2 * sqrt(n) *  sqrt(sqrt(n)) = n^(2+ 0.5 + 0.25) = n^(2.75)
```

Comment: Wrong on two accounts: The inner loop isn't sqrt (sqrt (n)). This is obvious if you replace the two loops with "for (j = i; j < sqrt (n); ++j)" and "for (k = j; k < sqrt (n); ++k). The other problem is that when i > sqrt (n), the j loop doesn't execute at all; just takes constant time to check that it doesn't execute. "result" will be set to O (n^1.5). The outer loop executes n^2 times, which makes the whole code O (n^2).

Comment: @gnasher729 That analysis may be worth posting as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Formal steps (need to be verified) using Sigma Notation would yield the following:

[image]
[image]